# Elegant way to get value_type from referenced container C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to get the value_type from a referenced container (e.g. `std::string& str`)

The only way I was able to do so is first to strip the reference and then access the underlying type, this way:

```
std::unordered_set<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(str)>::value_type>
```

If I was using C++11 it would be even worst:

```
std::unordered_set<std::remove_reference<decltype(str)>::type::value_type>
```

I find it to be too verbose and not very clean.

**Is there is any template in STL that does this kind of operation in a cleaner manner?**

Comment: Try `decltype(*str.begin())`

Comment: Also, `std::decay` is shorter and is effectively equivalent to `std::remove_reference` in this case, so `std::decay_t<decltype(str)>::value_type`

Comment: `std::string::value_type` should work just fine. Is there a reason for not doing it directly? (that is, is the question missing an important constraint?)

Comment: @PeteBecker, the whole reason is to not use the std::string directly. e.g. if I would change the argument type to std::wstring I would still want that to work w/o changing any of the function code.

Comment: It's easy to write your own type-transformations.

Answer (score 0):

C++20 adds [iterator trait aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iter_t) that allow you do this exact thing in combination with `std::begin` and its siblings.

The following names the `value_type` of anything `c` you can get a begin iterator from, including legacy built-in arrays:

```cpp
std::itr_value_t<decltype(std::begin( c ))>;
```

It's only a bit shorter, so maybe make that a template metafunction.